# Glibc importance of error 

Tags: glibc, linux

I am following LFS 6.7, and I reached the point where I compile glibc-2.12.1 .

I mounted the LFS partition with the atime option:
here is a confirm on that I think:
`/dev/sdb1 on /mnt /lfs type ext4 (rw)`

I get the following errors on making the test, and I have no clue if I should try to resolve them, or just ignore them and go on ...

```
rpc/types.h sunrpc/rpc/svc_auth.h sunrpc/rpcsvc/bootparam.h sysvipc/sys/ipc.h \
   sysvipc/sys/msg.h sysvipc/sys/sem.h sysvipc/sys/shm.h termios/termios.h \
   termios/sys/termios.h termios/sys/ttychars.h time/time.h time/sys/time.h \
   time/sys/timeb.h wcsmbs/wchar.h wctype/wctype.h > \
        /sources/glibc-build/begin-end-check.out
make[1]: Target `check' not remade because of errors.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/sources/glibc-2.12.1'
make: *** [check] Error 2

root:/sources/glibc-build# grep Error glibc-check-log
make[2]: *** [/sources/glibc-build/math/test-float.out] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/sources/glibc-build/math/test-ifloat.out] Error 1
make[1]: *** [math/tests] Error 2
make[2]: [/sources/glibc-build/posix/annexc.out] Error 1 (ignored)
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

thanks in advance, Oz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely ignore this error when build LFS.

Comment: Why? Please explain.

Comment: Because the float math tests are not critical for building and work. Result of the passage may depend on the CPU.

Comment: THANK YOU ! I was really puzzled by this ! I wish there was another opinion, but i will settle for your only :-)